# Difference between Maven and Gradle runtime (scope/configuration)?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies, runtime

Why there is a difference between the two concepts. Yes, they decide to write it in this way but for everything there is reasonable purpose.

In **Gradle** [documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#configurations):

```
runtime
The dependencies required by the production classes at runtime. By default, also includes the compile time dependencies.
```

.. **includes the compile time dependencies.**

In [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

```
runtime
This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath
```

...**but not the compile classpath**

.